# Post-Incrementing/decrementing in recursive method calls (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, post-increment, pre-increment

Say you have a recursive method, and you post-increment/decrement a value in the recursive call.  Why will this result in a stack overflow exception when a pre-increment/decrement will not?

Ex.

```
numberCount(currentNumber++); //Stack overflow exception

numberCount(++currentNumber); //No stack overflow exception
```

Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first

```
numberCount(currentNumber++); //Stack overflow exception
```

is equivalent to:

```
numberCount(currentNumber);
currentNumber += 1;
```

while the the second

```
numberCount(++currentNumber); //No stack overflow exception
```

is equivalent to

```
currentNumber += 1;
numberCount(currentNumber);
```

Need I explain more?

Comment: I'd add that IMO, this is why you should always use the ++ operator on its own line (except in for loops).  That way you don't have to think about this problem.

Comment: @DerrekWhistle: If the answer was helpful, please don't forget to accept it (checkmark next to it), and maybe even upvote it.

Comment: I can't upvote until my rep increases, but i'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `numberCount(currentNumber++);`, if an Exception is thrown by `numberCount` function, will the variable `currentNumber` incremented?